# Removing Single Id from Repeated Values in Java

Tags: java

I am having a string with below value:

```
String id = "21713|4 Pieces=50,21701|2 pieces=35,21701|250 Gram=30,21701|250 Gram=30,21701|250 Gram=30,";
```

The above id have `21701|250 Gram=30` repeated three times. All I want to do is, when I click on remove item button which will pass no. of counts, only that much count of `21701|250 Gram=30` should be removed.

How can we handle this?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option you have, is to parse the String into a Map which stores the count of repetitions.
Using this Map you can then rebuild the String after you pressed your buttons.

Limitation: You might run into problems if the order of the string parts is important.

IMHO to have such a String in your application to begin with seems like bad design. (unless its a exercise)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String remove(String id, int countToRemove) {
    Set<String> set = Stream.of(id.split("(?<=,)"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == countToRemove)
        .map(e -> e.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return Stream.of(id.split("(?<=,)"))
        .filter(s -> !set.contains(s))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

And

```
String id = "21713|4 Pieces=50,21701|2 pieces=35,21701|250 Gram=30,21701|250 Gram=30,21701|250 Gram=30,";
System.out.println(remove(id, 3));
```

result:

```
21713|4 Pieces=50,21701|2 pieces=35,
```

In java7

```
static String remove(String id, int countToRemove) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : id.split("(?<=,)")) {
        Integer value = map.get(key);
        if (value == null)
            value = 0;
        map.put(key, value + 1);
    }
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet())
        if (e.getValue() == countToRemove)
            set.add(e.getKey());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String key : id.split("(?<=,)"))
        if (!set.contains(key))
            sb.append(key);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, Unfortunately I won't be able to use Java8. Can you please give solution using Java7?

Comment: really thanks mate. But Collectors are part of Java8. ;-(

Comment: That's giving a wrong output. countToRemove is working as index instead of number of times it should remove that matching element. ;-(